# Why won't this decode to the html entity?

Tags: php, html-encode

Try it yourself:

```
echo(html_entity_decode("&hellip;"));
```

It echos `&hellip;` instead of `…` as it should.

Why won't this decode and how can I make it do so?

Comment: um that is not going to work like that

Comment: @Ibrahim Diallo I'm aware, I wouldn't have posted this otherwise. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the default ISO-8859-1 target character set does not contain the "…" character. You'll have to explicitly target UTF-8:

```
html_entity_decode('&hellip;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

Note that this changed in PHP 5.3.3 where UTF-8 became the default.

Comment: Your code generates: `â€¦` which, while it looks cool, is not an ellipsis.

Comment: @Cyclone Then your document is not being interpreted as UTF-8. Either target the charset that you are serving your document as or fix how your document is served.

Comment: `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` did the trick for that, by the way. Thank you!